# JTextField and JComboBox make my JPanel disappear from the screen

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

whenever I uncomment my JTextField or JComboBox they make all my swing elements disappear, I've tried resizing them and manipulating them in any way but I have no clue as to why the stuff is disappearing. They weren't on a previous program I wrote and they're wrote the exact same way. They elements even disappear if the two objects aren't even added to the panel.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code I have for my program. I don't really want to separate the 2 panels into their own Classes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create window
        JFrame window = new Window();
        String[] optionsToChoose = {"Car Parts", "Fast Food", "Groceries", "Clothing", "Gas", "Store", "Entertainment"};
        
        // Create first screen
        JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
        startPanel.setLayout(null);
        startPanel.setBounds(230, 230, 500, 250);
        startPanel.setBackground(new Color(177, 177, 177));
        
        JLabel header = new JLabel("CHOOSE AN ACTION");
        header.setForeground(Color.white);
        header.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        header.setBounds(0, -25, 500, 150);
        
        JButton add = new JButton("ADD");
        add.setBackground(new Color(0, 109, 91));
        add.setForeground(Color.white);
        add.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
        add.setBounds(90, 125, 150, 50);
        
        JButton view = new JButton("VIEW REPORT");
        view.setBackground(new Color(167, 199, 231));
        view.setForeground(Color.white);
        view.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
        view.setBounds(270, 125, 150, 50);
        
        startPanel.add(view);
        startPanel.add(add);
        startPanel.add(header);

        startPanel.setVisible(false);
        
        // Create second screen
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setBounds(230, 220, 500, 300);
        addPanel.setLayout(null);
        addPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        JLabel header2 = new JLabel("INPUT DATA BELOW:");
        header2.setBounds(0, -25, 500, 150);
        header2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        header2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        header2.setForeground(Color.white);
        
        JLabel costHeader = new JLabel("COST:");
        costHeader.setForeground(Color.white);
        costHeader.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        costHeader.setBounds(90, 75, 150, 50);
        
        JLabel typeHeader = new JLabel("TYPE:");
        typeHeader.setBounds(300, 75, 150, 50);
        typeHeader.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        typeHeader.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        
        JTextField costInput = new JTextField("$0", 10);
        costInput.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        costInput.setBounds(90, 150, 150, 50);
        costInput.setForeground(Color.white);
        
        JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(optionsToChoose);
        jComboBox.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        jComboBox.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 50); 
        
        addPanel.add(jComboBox);
        addPanel.add(costInput);
        addPanel.add(typeHeader);
        addPanel.add(header2);
        addPanel.add(costHeader);
        
        addPanel.setVisible(true);
        
        // Add components
        window.add(startPanel);
        window.add(addPanel);
    }
}
```

Here's the Window class as well:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window() {
        this.setTitle("Finance Tracker");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);
        //this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(1000, 800);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(177, 177, 177));
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea as to why this could be happening, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `startPanel.setLayout(null);` well, that's not helping

Comment: It all works before those 2 are added, I'm still very new to GUI creation and I haven't really gotten a handle on how LayoutManagers work, and yes I've read the APIs they just seem.. weird

Comment: It's weird cause even if they're not added to the panel, their instantiation causes it to not work...

Comment: Layout managers make your life a lot simpler - your code "works", but I don't know what `Window` is, seems to be custom class, so that might the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added the Window class to the edit, I don't believe that should be the issue to be honest, its just a generic JPanel class I made.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Why would you even attempt to use a negative x/y value? This is why you should be using layout managers. They set the size/location of components so you don't have to provide random values that don't always make sense. We won't spend time helping with null layouts because they should NOT be used. Take the time to learn to use layout managers. * its just a generic JPanel class I made* - 1) classes should have descriptive names. 2) is it not a panel, you extend JFrame.

Comment: The problem may be with the fact that you make the window visible before the you add the components ... not to mention `java.awt.Window` already exists, so, yeah, confusion all round.  Remove `this.setVisible(true);` from the constuctor and add `window.setVisible(true)` to the end of the `main` method

Comment: `startPanel.setBounds(230, 230, 500, 250); ... addPanel.setBounds(230, 220, 500, 300);` - you are attempting to have two panels occupy the same space. The panel added first is painted last. These are the type of issue you have when you try to manually code size/location. Again, get rid of all the null layouts and setBounds and use layout managers so you don't have these issues. Layout managers exist to make life easier.

Comment: I was trying to make it to where I could flip between different JPanels in the window, I made a previous program switching between JFrames and I didn't really like the whole feel of that one. I don't fully know what I'm doing just messing around with it and learning.

@camickr You could've at least tried to be helpful bro, I don't have a ton of experience in OOP and the one language I'm really good at doesn't use LayoutManagers or anything, you manually set the size and position, even if that means using negative integers. I meant JFrame, I'm tired bro, sorry.

Comment: *where I could flip between different JPanels in the window* - and the [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is specifically designed for this purpose. Take advantage of the API and don't reinvent the wheel. I have been helpful. What you use in other languages does not always translate to another language. You are learning Java/Swing which has layout managers. Other languages don't. So you should be taking the time to learn to use Swing the way it was designed to be used. In the long run you will be further ahead.

Comment: Okay I'll look into that Layout, thanks. I guess the issue is that these components just don't like one another with the way I'm doing things?

Comment: @camickr I just took it the wrong way sorry; I'll look more into the Swing API and learn more about its many components and their functionalities. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Provide ASCII art of the intended layouts of each (2 in all?) view.